# How to check the type of keyboard currently using on my app?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, qwerty

How to check the type of soft keyboard currently using in my app ?
Two types of soft keyboards are shown below (That I know)

[image: QWERTY]
QWERTY

[image: 123 Type Keyboard]
123 Type Keyboard

Comment: What do you mean by "type"?

Comment: type I mean, QWERTY or Num keypad (for entering English characters)